# Android google map check path in path

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

i have polyline of one road (list of latlng) and two location (start location,destination location). How can i check this two location are in the road with the same direction or not. Thank you for your time

Comment: what do you mean the same direction ? You're talking about points

Comment: that means from start location to destination location it make one path. i want to check if that path is in the previous path and have the same direction or not. it is used for my lift share app when you can find someone to give you a lift to somewhere

Comment: have you found a solution?